# Why is this query not inserting or failing, and seems not to be processed at all in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the Simple PDO wrapper singleton approach referenced at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper

I have the following query

```
                $new_app_insert_query = DB::run('INSERT INTO applicant_education_record (
                                        id_applicant_account,
                                        institution,
                                        diploma_certificate_type,
                                        dates_of_attendance,
                                        major,
                                        date_of_degree,
                                        gpa,
                                        city_of_institution,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution,
                                        institution_b,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_b,
                                        dates_of_attendance_b,
                                        major_b,
                                        date_of_degree_b,
                                        gpa_b,
                                        city_of_institution_b,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_b,
                                        institution_c,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_c,
                                        dates_of_attendance_c,
                                        major_c,
                                        date_of_degree_c,
                                        gpa_c,
                                        city_of_institution_c,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_c,
                                        institution_d,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_d,
                                        dates_of_attendance_d,
                                        major_d,
                                        date_of_degree_d,
                                        gpa_d,
                                        city_of_institution_d,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_d,
                                        institution_e,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_e,
                                        dates_of_attendance_e,
                                        major_e,
                                        date_of_degree_e,
                                        gpa_e,
                                        city_of_institution_e,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_e,
                                        institution_f,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_f,
                                        dates_of_attendance_f,
                                        major_f,
                                        date_of_degree_f,
                                        gpa_f,
                                        city_of_institution_f,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_f,
                                        institution_g,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_g,
                                        dates_of_attendance_g,
                                        major_g,
                                        date_of_degree_g,
                                        gpa_g,
                                        city_of_institution_g,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_g,
                                        institution_h,
                                        diploma_certificate_type_h,
                                        dates_of_attendance_h,
                                        major_h,
                                        date_of_degree_h,
                                        gpa_h,
                                        city_of_institution_h,
                                        state_or_country_of_institution_h,
                                        transcript_a,
                                        transcript_b,
                                        transcript_c,
                                        transcript_d,
                                        transcript_e,
                                        transcript_f,
                                        transcript_g,
                                        transcript_h) 
                                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',$binds);
                                        header("Location: ../new_app_acct_4.php");
```

My bind array looks like:

```
$binds = [
                $_POST['id_applicant_account'],
                $_POST['institution'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type'],
                $dates_of_attendance,
                $_POST['major'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree'],
                $_POST['gpa'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution'],

                $_POST['institution_b'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_b'],
                $dates_of_attendance_b,
                $_POST['major_b'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_b'],
                $_POST['gpa_b'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_b'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_b'],

                $_POST['institution_c'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_c'],
                $dates_of_attendance_c,
                $_POST['major_c'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_c'],
                $_POST['gpa_c'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_c'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_c'],

                $_POST['institution_d'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_d'],
                $dates_of_attendance_d,
                $_POST['major_d'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_d'],
                $_POST['gpa_d'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_d'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_d'],

                $_POST['institution_e'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_e'],
                $dates_of_attendance_e,
                $_POST['major_e'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_e'],
                $_POST['gpa_e'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_e'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_e'],

                $_POST['institution_f'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_f'],
                $dates_of_attendance_f,
                $_POST['major_f'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_f'],
                $_POST['gpa_f'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_f'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_f'],

                $_POST['institution_g'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_g'],
                $dates_of_attendance_g,
                $_POST['major_g'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_g'],
                $_POST['gpa_g'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_g'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_g'],

                $_POST['institution_h'],
                $_POST['diploma_certificate_type_h'],
                $dates_of_attendance_h,
                $_POST['major_h'],
                $_POST['date_of_degree_h'],
                $_POST['gpa_h'],
                $_POST['city_of_institution_h'],
                $_POST['state_or_country_of_institution_h'],
                'no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no'
            ];
```

When I run my application, I don't get any MySQL or php errors. The form submits successfully, then redirects to new_app_acct_4.php. The database isn't updated with the newly inserted records, and neither PHP or MySQL throws any errors. Any suggestions for trying to troubleshoot are appreciated.

Comment: What does your php log say though?

Comment: I'm not going to count those question marks, but that would be the first thing I check. Also, this is really terrible database design. What happens when someone has attended 9 schools? And how much space are you wasting for the vast majority of students who have attended one school? You should normalize the database so other school data are in a separate table.

Comment: And, if you want to debug this problem, I'd suggest getting rid of the DB class you're using. It saves you two lines of code, is it really worth the trouble?

Comment: "…neither PHP or MySQL throws any errors" → And did you instruct PHP and your DB class to show any errors to begin with? Just leaning back and observing nothing is not a very practical approach.

Comment: @miken32 I'm aware it's a terrible db design. This is an inherited application that we are bandaging to work right now. A full refactor is up next. 

Also, why get rid of the DB class? It promotes encapsulation and prevents me from having to re-instantiate pdo every time, provide credentials each time. Why would using this wrapper prevent MySQL and PHP from throwing errors.

Comment: @mario6 of course PHP and MySQL have been configured to throw errors. This DB class has worked for over 300 other queries in the app so far, and troubleshooting them was a matter of simply responding to PHP/MYSQL error

Comment: Are you catching errors? You don't show your code so hard to tell.

Comment: You can try enabling the general log on the mysql server to see what query is being passed.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the value of `$new_app_insert_query`.  If `PDO::prepare()` fails, it returns `FALSE` - so if `$new_app_insert_query` is `FALSE`, you know that the `PDO::prepare()` failed.  If it returns a `PDOStatement` object, then use `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` to see if the statement executed successfully, or if it resulted in an error.